# check a list constantly and do something if list has items

Tags: python, list, queue, iteration, gevent

I have a global list where items are added constantly (from network clients):

```
mylist = []
def additem(uuid,work):
    mylist.append(uuid,work)
```

And a function which should check the list and if there are items proceed them:

```
def proceeditems():

  while True:
    itemdone = []
    if len(mylist) > 0:
     for item in mylist:
       try:
          #This can go wrong and than need to be done again 
          result = gevent.spawn(somework(item))
          #result returns the uuid
          itemdone.append(result.value)
       except:
          pass
    for item in itemdone:
        mylist[:] = [value for value in mylist if value[0]!=item]
```

So I hope you get an idea now what I try to do, but I think the endless loop seems to be not the right solution.

Comment: Perhaps a [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is better here?

Comment: You _do_ want an endless loop… but you want an endless loop that _waits_ for something, instead of spinning as fast as possible. You can use a `Condition` for that… but if you get it right, you will be reproducing exactly what `Queue` does, and if you don't get it right (which you won't, the first 30 times or so), you will have something useless and painful to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of case, you must have used either multithreading or multiprocessing (depending whether the network client is running at different thread or different process.

In either case, you should use [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/queue.html) to manage the incoming data, then store into `itemdone` afterwards.

You define the queue like this:

```
my_queue = queue.Queue() # or multiprocessing.Queue()
```

Then later you should include the queue in the arguments (or if you use threading, you can use global queue, like you did)

```
def additem(uuid,work,the_queue):
    the_queue.put((uuid,word)) # Queue in a tuple containing the data

def proceeditems(the_queue):
    while True:
        item = the_queue.get() # This will block until something is inside the queue
        try:
            result = somework(item)
            itemdone.append(result)
        except:
            the_queue.put(item) # If failed, put back to queue for retry.
        # You don't need the last two lines
```

To stop the whole process, you can make the `additem` function to insert special token, and the `proceeditems`, upon receiving the special token, will just quit the loop.

Comment: yeah you are right i use gevent. The problem with queue is that i need to run the somework function for all items because some might work and others dont and i cant block the possible working ones in the queue

Comment: @W0bble: Well, `gevent` _isn't_ multithreading or multiprocessing. But the answer is basically the same, except that you want a [`gevent.queue.Queue`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html) instead of a stdlib `queue.Queue`.

Comment: @W0bble: Meanwhile, "some might work and others dont and i cant block the possible working ones" doesn't make any sense as an explanation of why you can't use a queue. If they'd get stuck in the queue, they'd get stuck in the un-synchronized list in exactly the same way. There is no difference, except that the queue actually works while the list requires you to burn CPU and has race conditions.

Comment: @W0bble: Finally, it sounds like you may want a [pool](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html) of workers to service the tasks concurrently, instead of a queue with a single worker servicing it. But if so, that's no harder.

Comment: Ok thank you guys I will think about the Queue option again. After some hours I forgot why I throw it away in the first place